# Execute Asynccallback truly asynchronously while retrieving delegate return value

Tags: c#, asynchronous

So basically I'm invoking a delegate with BeginInvoke I'm passing the AsyncCallback as well. Whenever the callback gets executed I want to retrieve the delegate return value and do something with it but to do that I need to call EndInvoke which Blocks main thread which is not what I desire. I want that callback to execute truly asynchronously. Can It be done in this way ? if not are there any other ways ? my async callback method looks like this for now

```
private void RegisterUserAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var something = (Something)result.AsyncState;
    var asyncCaller = (AsyncMethodCaller)((AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate;
    var responce = asyncCaller.EndInvoke(result);

    if (responce.Success)
    {
        something.SomeId = SomeId.Active;
        someDAL.UpdateSomething(something );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [Task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) (.NET 4.0 or higher), or `async`/`await` (.NET 4.5)?

Comment: to use those I would need those methods to return Task<SomeResponse> to be awaitable but I don't want to do that.

Comment: No, that is not necessary. Maybe [this](http://pastebin.com/4zDvY96c) is helpful? Other than that, the code snippet you have posted seems fine, but it contradicts your comment "... I need to call EndInvoke which Blocks main thread ...". The function `RegisterUserAsyncCallback` should never be called on the main thread; it will be on a random worker thread automatically called once the delegate finishes.